# Generate output as list instead of multiple lines

Tags: python, list

I want to display the files and folders inside a directory in a specific format.

The folder looks like this:

```
/home/test_directory
    fg-2022-07-12
    fg-2022-07-11
    ag-2022-07-12
```

My code to display certain elements of the folder:

```
SRC = '/home/test_directory'

for root_dir_path, sub_dirs, files in os.walk(SRC):
    for folders in sub_dirs:
        if "fg-" in folders:
            print(folders)
```

Current output:

```
fg-2022-07-08
fg-2022-07-07
```

Desired output:

```
['fg-2022-07-08', 'fg-2022-07-07']
```

Preferably, I would like to generate the list **instead** of the multiple lines, but converting the multiple lines (current output) into a list would work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SRC = '/home/test_directory'

output = []
for root_dir_path, sub_dirs, files in os.walk(SRC):
    for folders in sub_dirs:
        if "fg-" in folders:
            output.append(folders)
print(output)
```

What you want is to output the list instead of the elements. A much smaller example would be:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 1]
for x in l:
    # when printing strings, quotes are omitted
    print(x)
```

This outputs:

```
a
b
1
```

Quote are not omitted when you print the list

```
print(l)
```

This prints:

```
['a', 'b', 1]
```